# Solr Error during installation - Unable to connect to remote server - Sitecore 10.3

Tags: solr, installation

This is my local machine running on `Windows 11 Pro`. It already has a Sitecore instance `v10.1.2` with `Solr-8.4.0` running on port `8983`.

Now, I'm trying to install `Sitecore 10.3`. This has installed `Solr-8.11.2` and I had specified port `8984`.

During the 2/2 task of installation, it stops at this error.

[image]

When I browse the portal - `https://localhost:8984/solr', it loads fine and I can also see the indexes.

[image]

I could not find the `sxa` indices though!

The databases and the sites are also installed and I can browse the CMS & the site.

1. What is the reason for this error.
2. How can I check that the installation was successful.
3. Even after selecting the checkbox to install SXA, it was not installed.

**UPDATE 1:**

Unfortunately, the suggestions - increasing the delay & stopping anti-virus did not work.
SXA is not being installed.
The installation fail with the same error.

**UPDATE 2**

I have managed to install the instance by running the PowerShell script  `XP0-SingleDeveloper.ps1` instead of using the GUI.
However, this doesn't install SXA.
For that, I had to install separate packages for SXA & PowerShell Extensions.

Comment: Are you able to run the CMS and build the indexes?

Comment: @SumitBhatia There was a solr exception when populating schema and rebuilding indexes for core index.

Answer (score 1):

You can try updating the value of `PostDelay` under the file `Solr-SingleDeveloper.json` so it will look like this.

```
"StartSolr": {
"Description" : "Starts the Solr service.",
            "Type": "ManageService",
            "Params":{
                "Name": "[parameter('SolrService')]",
                "Status": "Running",
                "PostDelay": 15000
            }
        },
```

Refer to this article for this kind of issue while installation.

[Unable to connect to the remote server](https://www.valtech.com/en-in/blog/sitecore-9.1-installation-error--unable-to-connect-to-the-remote-server/)

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can try it out by disabling the `antivirus`. As per Martin miles experiment it could be the reason.

   After experiments, I found out that was an `antivirus` preventing such requests. `Disabling` it allowed cores to be installed well and the rest of the install script succeeded.
2. You can validate the CMS instance and log files to validate if the instance looks good or not.

Refer link: [Unable to connect to Solr server, while it is available](https://blog.martinmiles.net/post/sitecore-9-installer-unable-to-connect-to-remote-server)

Hope it helps!